# Pure .NET Canvas Implementation

Tags: .net, xna

Some background: I'm trying to implement a 2D canvas in C#/.NET for deployment in an XNA game. I'd like the game to work on non-Windows platforms, so I'm trying to avoid the native calls that come with System.Drawing or other GDI+ implementations. The canvas would need to support traditional operations (fill/stroke shapes and paths, transformations, clipping). I've managed a rough implementation that looks pretty good and supports most of the the above, just by setting individual pixels in an int array. It's reasonably efficient for most things, but it takes a pretty bad performance hit when drawing large shapes (for obvious reasons - more pixels to fill). I'd like to see how other canvas implementations address this.

My questions is if anyone knows of a pure .NET canvas implementation I could use/work off of. Alternately, if anyone knows of a non-.NET open-source canvas implementation that I could use as a reference, that would great too.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [MonoGame](http://www.monogame.net/) - it's a multiplatform port of XNA running on .Net (Windows), Mono (Linux, OS X) and Xamarin (iOS, Android). I think there is no need for you to implement a software renderer by yourself.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but I believe Mono's implementation of [System.Drawing](http://www.mono-project.com/Drawing) still uses a native backend; it just has one for each platform. Xbox won't have one. Though your suggestions did lead me to their native implementation, using [Cairo](http://www.cairographics.org/) which might make a good starting place.